# Arduino liquidCrystal displayconstructor error

Tags: c++, arduino, lcd

I am using Visual Micro and I am trying to connect my LCD display to my Arduino Uno. The display has I2C and the address is 0x27. The problem is that when I try to create the constructor to put the pins,it does not allow me to do so. There is an error when I hover on the address 0x27.

Also when I try to run another project in Arduino IDE with the same library I had no issues and the LCD was fine.

I am sure that the issue could be the library, but the problem is that in the morning I had no such issues when I worked on it,after some time I wanted to continue to work on it but I had this error. Here is  that shows exactly what I mean.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3);

int led = 8;
int button = 7;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button, INPUT);
    lcd.begin(16,2);
}
```

The error comes from 0x27.When I hover over it it gives me this error.

> no instance of constructor matches the argument list            argument types are: (int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)

Can somebody help me figure out the issue,thanks !

Comment: You need to look at the constructor for that class and see what parameters it takes.

Comment: According to the source code found [here](https://github.com/fdebrabander/Arduino-LiquidCrystal-I2C-library/blob/master/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h) it only takes 4 parameters, you have 9. Maybe you are using a different library?

Comment: Maybe,I will try this one that you provided

Comment: Ok. Just note that I have never used that library. My comment was based on a simple web search so I can't attest to it's quality.